# Read BPW21R photodiode

Tags: photodiode

I want to sample the output of a BPW21R photodiode [Datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81519/bpw21r.pdf). 
I intend to use an Arduino.

If the resolution is not good enough for the Arduino analog input pin (A0) [Arduino Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins) then I want to use a ADS1115 [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the anticipated photocurrent? Can you measure it? And are you after any particular frequency response?

Comment: Only thing i did I put directly between gnd and A0 and when I put a flashlight over it i get some increase in reading values, but i guess this is not the right way to read it...

Comment: This question might be of help https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428597/photodiode-circuit-questions?rq=1

Comment: You need a transimpedance amp unless you're doing something like shining a laser at it which produces a large enough signal to use directly. http://ti.com/lit/pdf/TIDU535