# Monitor Photodiode polarity convention

Tags: photodiode

I have Monitor Photodiode specs that claim the following:

- MPD Reverse Voltage: -10V Min, -3V Max
- MPD Forward Current: 0mA Min,    10 mA Max

What is the convention for measuring this voltage and current? Would I measure the voltage the same as I would a normal diode (positive lead on anode, negative lead on cathode), and this would produce a negative voltage (implying that the photodiode operates normally in a reversed-biased configuration)?

For the forward current, would a positive current be flowing in the direction of the diode "arrow" symbol, or opposite?

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428597/photodiode-circuit-questions

Comment: Essentially, you apply a reverse voltage to the photodiode and the photodiode produces a reverse current that is approximately proportional to the irradiance.